# Code throwing java.net.SocketExpection

Tags: java, c3p0, socketexception

I'm requesting some data from a remote database, using the c3p0 pool of connections approach. I can nicely retrieve all the data I need, but for some reason, that apparently seems to be related with network socket, I'm getting the `java.net.SocketException` according to this stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3697)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3586)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4131)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2820)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2769)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyStatement.java:327)
at MemsqlRequester.run(MemsqlRequester.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:112)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:159)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
... 9 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
at GraphTransformer$$anonfun$getTxInformationList$1.apply$mcVI$sp(GraphTransformer.scala:38)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
at GraphTransformer.getTxInformationList(GraphTransformer.scala:37)
at GraphTransformer.getFeaturesTx(GraphTransformer.scala:62)
at GraphTransformer.getFeatures(GraphTransformer.scala:327)
at GraphDatasetBuilder.lambda$publishGraphFeaturesFromMemsql$13(GraphDatasetBuilder.java:62)
at java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1249)
at GraphDatasetBuilder.publishGraphFeaturesFromMemsql(GraphDatasetBuilder.java:59)
at GraphDatasetBuilder.main(GraphDatasetBuilder.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Basically the code snippet where I do the statement calls to retrieve my data from the remote dataset are below:

```
try {
   ...
   Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(this.queryList.get(queryIndex)); // According to the stack trace, here is where I'm getting the SocketException
   ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that I can add any `catch` clause surrounding this code because it tells me no `SocketException` is being thrown. Basically my question is what's going wrong here, considering that apparently I can't handle a `SocketException` in my code as stated in the stack trace.

Comment: You left out the first line of the stack trace. The one with the exception in it. And the message. That tells you what the problem is.

Comment: So the exception is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: No, that is a subsequent exception, and if you're asking about that you shouldn't be, it is a trivial programming error. You still haven't provided the first line of the original exception. The one you're actually asking about, or should be. Hint: it is an `SQLException,` or something derived from one.

Comment: Hey @EJP, it is a CommunicationsException

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace that you have posted is not complete, we cannot see what exception has been thrown.

If you cannot catch the SocketException, I presume that the exception that you are receiving is a different one.

The SocketException is caught by the driver and re-thrown as a different exception. The SocketException that you can see in the stack trace is only the "caused by", that is the original exception that has been caught.

**Update**

You cannot catch The SocketException because it is not the exception that you receive. Please paste the full stack trace.

It seems that the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is a new exception. I can be wrong, but I do not think that  the driver would throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This exception seems thrown by spark.

I am not absolutely sure, but it seems to me that:

1) There is a network problem and you cannot access the database and open the connection;

2) A SocketException is thrown in the driver;

3) This Exception is caught and re-thrown as a different exception (the stack trace is incomplete and the exception thrown is not visible yet, but I guess that is a CommunicationsException);

4) As a consequence, the spark's code that is trying to read a graph fails and throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;

Comment: The exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but yes, the root cause is that `SocketException` that I'd like to catch if that's possible

Comment: I think that you should catch the exception CommunicationsException (if I am not wrong this is the exception that the driver throws).

Comment: @SauloRicci The root cause of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not and can never be a `SocketException.`

Comment: @MarcoAltieri yes, exactly is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. And yes, you got the exactly scenario

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update. If you do not need other info and you think that the answer was right, could you set the answer as accepted ? :)